# How to change rectangle background only from layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I did duplicate layer of rectangle shape ! The orignial has red background .I want to change the copied one background but when I change background it cover the whole page. How can I change the rectangle shape only ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Apply a Layer Style:**

- Double-click directly on the layer in the Layers Panel
- Choose 'Color Overlay', click on the color-picker box and (wait for it) pick your new color:

[image: Layer Style Dialog]

Aaaaaaaaand Done:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Magic Wand to select only the rectangle and fill up your colour desired with Paint Bucket Tool.

Or use Ctrl+Click (Window)/ Command+click (Mac) on the layer to select the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click (<kbd>Command</kbd>+click on Mac) on the layer thumbnail, it will create a selection around the shape.

Then simply choose another foreground colour, and click `Edit` > `Fill` - select the Foreground colour option.

Just a note for future reference: to change the colour of just one thing in Photoshop you nearly always need to make a selection first. There are many ways to make selections in Photoshop, some of the other answers here give alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The red rectangle is in own layer. Select that layer in the Layers panel. Goto Image > Adjustments > Hue & Saturation and change the red color to what you want.

Another option: select the emptiness around the rectangle by the Magic Wand tool with low tolerance. Then goto Select > Invert to get the rectangle selected. Finally with the Paint Bucket or a brush repaint the area.